# Understand which in a list of dynamic attached elements belonging to same class is tapped/clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm developing a web app to search items on a catalogue, so I wrote a script to dynamically attach to a unordered list a li item beloging to '.item' class. 
My problem is that for every item, I want open a specific page(not yet implemented) that describes his features, but  with the following piece of javascript code doesn't work for my purpose

```
$(".item").on("tap", function () {
  window.open("item_page.html");
   });
```

because it can't discriminate beetween the items since all the items, for styling reasons, are in the '.item' class. Then, when I click/tap on a item, a lot of new windows are opened, instead of only one.
In summary, I'd like that when I tap/click on an item, only the linked page is opened and not others.
I tried also working on 'id' istead of 'class' assigning an id to every item created, but it doesn't work. Any ideas to fix the problem?

--EDIT--
That's the piece of document where I insert the items:

```
     <div id="items-wrapper" data-role="main">
        <ul id="items-list">
         <!--here I insert the items-->
        </ul>
    </div><!--end items-wrapper>-->
```

and that's the piece of the script(that works well) that I use to dynamically append the items to my "item-list":

```
 $("#items-list").append(
                        '<li class="item">' +
                        '<div class="item-photo-container">' +
                        '<img src="images/item_126.jpg" >' +
                        "</div><!--end item-photo-container-->" +
                        '<div class="item-info">'+
                        '<ul>' +
                        '<li><a><h3 class="item-name">' + title + '</h3></a></li>' +
                        '<li>' + aname + '</li>' +
                        '<li>' + date + '</li>' +
                        '</ul>' +
                        '</div><!--end item-info-->' +
                        '</li><!--end item-->'
                    );
```

Previously, I didn't specify that infos about items are retrieved by a json-ld file loaded by the client when the app is loaded for the first time, so I'm working only client-side.
At the address  http://il2colcodino.altervista.org/galileo you can find thw whole web app. Work is in progress, so if you want test it, wait 20-30 seconds on first load(no message will be displayed at the end of loading) before write something in the search bar and click on the magnifier.
I suggest to write few letters to find enough matches, as 're' or 'mo'. The catalogue is in Italian.

Comment: Provide us with html sample

Comment: What does the `.item` have that's unique and what do you plan to do with it? Possible for you to create a working snippet of what you are dealing with please? I would also like to recommend you check the browser console for errors.

Comment: maybe you just need a php for this, not jquery..

Comment: @Gagantous what use would php be and what advantage would it have for this?

Comment: @Gagantous I'm sorry, I didn't specify that I work only client-side  and so I don't have any database from where retrieving the items infos.

Comment: @NewToJs I create the ".item" class for styling reasons( all the items have to have the same font, same dimensions etc...). In console there aren't any error, related to that, unfortunately. My final goal is that tapping/clicking on a item, a related description page will be open. The problems is that, in the moment I'm writing, clicking on a random item, all the pages of all items are opened istead of only the wanted page.

Comment: @NewToJS I put online the whole app, you should be able to see html document and all linked scripts and styling sheets. Wait a bit on the first load before try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is with `this`. In other words

`var myItems = document.getElementsByClassName("items");`

Then simply loop that array/collection attaching a click listener.

```
    try {
        for (var i = 0; i < myItems.length; i++) {
            myItems[i].onclick = function() {
                doSomething(this.innerHTML);
            };
        }
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log('error is ' + e);
    }
```

Comment: I solved the problem following this way, I've simply re-wrote it using Jquery $('#items-list').each(function () { $(this).on('tap',function () { window.open('item_page.html'); }) })

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but it seems you are attaching the event multiple times and that's why the page is being opened more than once. You need to make sure you are not attaching the event each time you append the element to the list because by attaching the event in the way you do it, you are attaching it to all `.item` elements on the page.
What I would do (this is just a suggestion since you didn't share the rest of your code), is to attach the event to the container and not to the element and to it only once. For example:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <ul id='my-list'>
      <li class='item' data-page='my-page.html'>My appended item 1</li>
      <!--li class='item' data-page='my-page-2.html'>More will be appended dynamically</li-->
    </ul>
  </body>
  <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
      jQuery('#my-list').on('tap', '.item', function (e) {
        var page = jQuery(this).data('page');
        window.open(page); //In case you cannot add an <a></a> opening the page for any reason (which be ideal)
      });
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, I fairly new on JS and Jquery, the 'e' used in the function must refer to the 'tap' event, right?

Comment: Yup, `e` is the event.